# Java cannot find the class no matter what I try

Tags: java

I keep on getting "error: cannot find symbol" for class Frog whenever I compile class Pond, even though there is no such error with class Fly.

Main class, Pond:

```
package flyFrogPond;
public class Pond {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Frog frogPeepo = new Frog("Peepo");
        Frog frogPepe = new Frog("Pepe", 10, 15);
        Frog frogPeepaw = new Frog("Peepaw", 4.6, 5);
        Frog frogPeepue = new Frog("Peepue");
        
        Fly fly1 = new Fly(1, 3);
        Fly fly2 = new Fly(6);
        Fly fly3 = new Fly();
        
        Frog.setSpecies("1331 Frogs");
        frogPeepo.toString();
        frogPeepo.eat(fly2);
        fly2.toString();
        frogPeepo.grow(8);
        frogPeepo.eat(fly2);
        fly2.toString();
        frogPeepo.toString();
        frogPeepue.toString();
        frogPeepaw.grow(4);
        frogPeepaw.toString();
        frogPepe.toString();
    }
}
```

Class Frog:

```
package flyFrogPond;
public class Frog{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private double tongueSpeed;
    private boolean isFroglet;
    private static String species;
    private double ageInYears;
    
    public static void setSpecies( String Species){ species = Species;}
    
    public Frog(String Name){
        name = Name;
        age = 5;
        tongueSpeed = 5;
        isFroglet = (age < 7 & age > 1) ? true : false;
        species = "Rare pepe";
    }
    
    public Frog(String Name, double AgeInYears, double TongueSpeed){
        name = Name;
        ageInYears = AgeInYears;
        tongueSpeed = TongueSpeed;
        age = (int) (ageInYears * 12);
        isFroglet = (age < 7 & age > 1) ? true : false;
        species = "Rare pepe";
    }
    
    public Frog(String Name, int Age, double TongueSpeed){
        name = Name;
        age = Age;
        tongueSpeed = TongueSpeed;
        isFroglet = (age < 7 & age > 1) ? true : false;
        //species = "Rare pepe";
    }
    
    public void grow(int addedAge) {
        while (age < 12 & addedAge > 0){
            age ++;
            tongueSpeed ++;
            addedAge --;
        }
        while (age < 30 & addedAge > 0){
            age ++;
            addedAge --;
        }
        while (addedAge > 0){
            age ++;
            tongueSpeed =- 0.5;
            addedAge --;
        }
        isFroglet = (age < 7 & age > 1) ? true : false;
    }
    
    public void grow() {
        int addedAge = 1;
        while (age < 12 & addedAge > 0){
            age ++;
            tongueSpeed ++;
            addedAge --;
        }
        while (age < 30 & addedAge > 0){
            age ++;
            addedAge --;
        }
        while (addedAge > 0){
            age ++;
            tongueSpeed =- 0.5;
            addedAge --;
        }
        isFroglet = (age < 7 & age > 1) ? true : false;
    }
    
    public void eat(Fly fly) {
        if (fly.isdead()) {
            
        } else if (tongueSpeed > fly.getSpeed()){
            grow();
            fly.setMass(0);
        } else{
            fly.growFly(1);
        }
    }
    
    public String toString(){
        if (isFroglet){
            return "My name is " + name + " and I’m a rare froglet! I’m " + age + " months old and my tongue has a speed of " + tongueSpeed + ".";
        } else{
            return "My name is " + name + " and I’m a rare frog! I’m " + age + " months old and my tongue has a speed of " + tongueSpeed + ".";
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, for good measure, class Fly

```
package flyFrogPond;
public class Fly{
    private double mass, speed;
    
    public void setMass( double Mass) { this.mass = Mass;}
    public void setSpeed( double Speed) { this.speed = Speed;}
    
    public double getMass() { return mass;}
    public double getSpeed() { return speed;}
    
    public Fly(){
        mass = 5;
        speed = 10;
    }
    
    public Fly(double Mass){
        mass = Mass;
        speed = 10;
    }
    
    public Fly(double Mass,double Speed){
        mass = Mass;
        speed = Speed;
    }
    
    public String toString(){
        if (mass == 0){
            return String.format("I’m dead, but I used to be a fly with a speed of %.2f", speed);
        } else{
            return String.format("I’m a speedy fly with %.2f and %.2f mass", speed, mass);
        }
    }
    
    public void growFly(int addedMass){
        while (mass < 20 & addedMass > 0){
            mass ++;
            speed ++;
            addedMass --;
        }
        while (addedMass > 0){
            mass ++;
            speed =- 0.5;
            addedMass --;
        }
    }
    
    public boolean isdead(){
        if (mass == 0){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried deleting various variables of Frog, to see if theywere the issue, changing the file location, and adding getters, none worked.

Here is the error message for those of you asking, i compiled and ran it in windows terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\gurna> javac F:\Notepad++\flyFrogPond\Frog.java
PS C:\Users\gurna> javac F:\Notepad++\flyFrogPond\Pond.java
F:\Notepad++\flyFrogPond\Pond.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
        Frog frogPeepo = new Frog("Peepo");
        ^
  symbol:   class Frog
  location: class Pond
F:\Notepad++\flyFrogPond\Pond.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
        Frog frogPeepo = new Frog("Peepo");
                             ^
  symbol:   class Frog
  location: class Pond
2 errors
```

Comment: How are your directory structured? How do you compile your program? How do you run your program?

Comment: I edited the post for the error message just now

Comment: Please have a look at how to write a [MCVE]

Comment: If you're going to work in that Notepad++ directory then you'd be better off creating a 'project' directory above your package root

Comment: Why use Notepad++ when there are IDEs like InteliJ or Eclipse which make creating project way more simple and does help a lot like content assist, compiling and running etc.

Comment: @GrindingForReputation *Why use Notepad++...* I've being programming Java since it started. I abandoned IDEs long ago apart from for niche cases. The OP will probably learn a lot more from *not* using an IDE, as well as hanging on to a great deal more memory and processing capacity for other work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C:\Users\gurna` is not your source root; you must run your compiler in the `F:\Notepad++` directory. How else can it know where to look for your other classes?

```
cd F:\Notepad++
javac flyFrogPond\Frog.java flyFrogPond\Pond.java
```

Comment: There are no errors but when I run "java flyFrogPond\Pond.java" afterwards nothing happens

Comment: @GalaxyBorb what do you expect to happen? Your code doesn't write any files or doesn't output anything

Comment: I added more code in pond that I expect to have an output.

Comment: @GalaxyBorb I sitll don't see any output in your program. Which statements do you expect to generate output? `.toString()` converts an object to its String representation, it doesn't write anything to your output

Comment: @GalaxyBorb none of that will have output. You must explicitly tell java to print it to the standard output

Comment: what you do is basically ask for a string, but do nothing with it.

Comment: I see, this is my first time using toString() lol

Comment: But this is a different question now. The posted question was "I get an error compiling my files". "My compiled code doesn't do what I expect it to do" is a [completely new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: imma solve this one by myself, it doesn't seem too complicated

Comment: yup, everything works perfectly

Comment: If you're going to work in that Notepad++ directory then you'd be better off creating a 'project' directory above your package root